# TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function. while trying to use it in a Reactjs Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

hello first time posting so i have been struggling with this error and tried fix of others here and it didnt work here is my firebase_init.js code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: ""
   authDomain:""
   projectId:""
   storageBucket:""
   messagingSenderId:""
   appId:""
   measurementId:""
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

And after checking documentation i copied these codes to index.html in the public folder of the react project:

```
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    
    // ...
    
    <script defer src="../src/firebase-init.js"></script>
```

still nothing worked, tried different imports, i also tried deleting node modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling, it just ended up messing up a whole lot of stuff in the node modules, so that didn't work either. So any help to solving this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update your firebase file to include the imports for the services you are planning to use. The script references may simply not be available at the time you are attempting to initialize auth and firestore:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
// static import of firestore
import "firebase/firestore";
// static import of auth
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: ""
   authDomain:""
   projectId:""
   storageBucket:""
   messagingSenderId:""
   appId:""
   measurementId:""
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

Keep in mind, this is for version 8 of firebase. The newer version at the time of this answer, version 9, will look pretty different:

```
import { initializeApp }  from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: ""
   authDomain:""
   projectId:""
   storageBucket:""
   messagingSenderId:""
   appId:""
   measurementId:""
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const auth = getAuth(db);

export { db, auth };
```

Comment: followed your solution and got a new error:   ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'app.container.getProvider').   ```

Comment: Are you using a bundler like webpack, rollup, or similar to process/compile/bundle your JS code? I assumed as such given you are using `import` statements in your JS files. You can't really use `import` in the web without something like a bundler.